# I've installed Mist which uses geth; so how do I launch geth from the command line?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I've installed Mist (using a dmg, on Mac OS X).

Mist runs great, and when I run it, it seems to be using geth.  How can I run geth from the command line without reinstalling it and without running Mist?

Answer (score 1):

Geth can be run from the command line like so: `geth {{parameters}}`.

Example of a basic one on the main net:

`geth`

Ropsten testnet:

`geth --testnet`

Ropsten testnet with modules exposed via rpc that only localhost can connect to:

`geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "127.0.0.1"`

A syncmode=light testnet anyone can connect to:

`geth --testnet --syncmode="light" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"`

You will need to specify some sort of rpccorsdomain for you to access the node.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the Geth folder. You can create a shortcut to it on your desktop.  could be somewhere like this on Win:

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked